# How to populate Html.EditorFor element based on input value in another HtmlEditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my Razor page i want to to populate an HtmlEditorFor element based on the input value in another  HtmlEditorFor element. Ideally im looking to execute a C# function on text changed event of the HtmlEditorFor. My function checks if the input value (a double in this case) falls within a range. The range is defined in a database table already existing.
Im looking for insight on whether to use a javascript function or as i prefer call a C# function/Controller. The javascript function would check if input value falls within a range then if it returns TRUE autofill a specific code to the other related input element.
In my NewRequistion.cshtml i have the elements as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Justification, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Justification, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Justification" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Justification, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
 <div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tier, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Justification" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: you can pre-populate the range values from your database into the HTML of the page (or inject them into some JavaScript code), so then you don't need to make another request to the server just to validate the range. Then you can use JavaScript to detect when the user typed into the box, check the value entered against the range data, and populate the other input box with the appropriate value. Far more user-friendly to do it using JavaScript

Comment: Of course, when the form is submitted you should still run some server-side validation as well as a backup, in case the client tried to bypass validation by turning off JavaScript or otherwise modifying the page using their browser tools. So at that moment you would again check the submitted value against the range values, and check that the value in the second field is correct relative to that.